# get json path to get value

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json object:

```
var config = 
{
    "data1" :
    {
        "emp1":
        {
            "phone" : "111",
            "address": "xxx"
        },
        "emp2":
        {
            "phone" : "111",
            "address": "xxx"
        }
    }   
}
```

In my function I pass the root object and the string of the name I want:

```
function getEmp(config, section)
{
}
```

config is the json object above.  Section is a string for either emp1 or emp2.
I would like to be able to combine for example use the function like so

```
var emp1Data = getEmp(config, 'emp1')
```

What is the best way to return that portion of the JSON object?

Ive tried:

```
function getEmp(config, section)
{
  return JSON.parse(config + '.' + emp);
}
```

but this fails.  I would like to be able to do it without looping in the function.

**Update 1**
My config object has an extra comma.  I have updated it

**Update 2**
I fixed my config object now

Comment: The first example creates an error.

Comment: that's not how to declare a json object

Comment: That's an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals), not JSON, which is a string-based data format.

Comment: @JaredFarrish No it is not. It is a syntax error.

Comment: This is not a JSON object. This is an object. And it actually returns an error if i run the var config code.

Comment: Your trailing comma isn't an issue in modern browsers. The issue is that you're starting the object with a `"data1"` instead of with a `{` and a `}` at the end.

Comment: The comma doesn't matter, it needs `{}` around the variable value.

Comment: So now you're saying you want to *search* for a nested property given a string? Because `emp1` isn't directly in `config`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Javascript Object:

```
var config = {
    "emp1":
    {
        "phone" : "111",
        "address": "xxx"
    },
    "emp2":
    {
        "phone" : "111",
        "address": "xxx"
    }
}
```

Then you could access it like so:

```
(function(config, section) {
  return config[section];
})(config, 'emp1');
```

Using `[]` notation to access the property of the `config` object, which is similar to `config.emp1`.

See the following MDN article on `[]` property accessor notation: [Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Property_names)

Answer (score 0):

Your config is poorly defined. You want something like:

```
var config =
{
    "emp1":
    {
        "phone" : "111",
        "address": "xxx"
    },
    "emp2":
    {
        "phone" : "111",
       "address": "xxx"
    }       
};
```

Then, to get what you want, you do (for example)

```
var blah = config["emp1"];
console.log( JSON.stringify( blah ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `for..in` loop to traverse through the different property names of the object and its children. See here for an example of what you want:

```
function getEmp(config, section)
{
    for(var cur in config){
        if(cur == section){
            return config[cur];
        }else if(typeof config[cur] == 'object'){
            var result = getEmp(config[cur], section);
            if(typeof result != 'undefined'){
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function deepGet(root, path) {
    let output = root;
    for (const e of path) output = output[e];
    return output;
}
```

Example:

```js
function deepGet(root, path) {
 let output = root;
 for (const e of path) output = output[e];
 return output;
}

const a = [];
a.b = [];
a.b.c = 'd';

console.log(deepGet(a, ['b', 'c']) === a.b.c);
console.log(deepGet(a, ['b']) === a.b);
console.log(deepGet(a, []) === a);
```

[**Benchmark**](https://jsbench.me/h8juhrjnsr/1)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `eval()` to do that

```
function getEmp(config, section)
{
    return eval( "(" + config + "." + section  + ")" )
}
```

but you will have to make sure `config` is a string, not an object.

Meaning: you will have to call that function like this:

```
var sec = getEmp('config','emp2');
```